# Export product data to CSV with PHP from Magento with flat catalog

Tags: php, magento

I have a Magento 1.9 store and already programmed an export script for exporting product data into a CSV file. After I turned the flat catalog on for an extension i missed some attributes SKU and Leverancier.

I Cold turn the flat catalog on and off while exporting but has anybody an idea of how to fix this with my code?

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd());
$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php'; 
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
Mage::app();
$products = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection();
$products->addAttributeToSelect('name');
$products->addAttributeToSelect('afmetingen');
$products->addAttributeToSelect('leverancier');
$products->addAttributeToSelect('price');
$fp = fopen('exports.csv', 'w');
$csvHeader = array("sku", "name", "afmetingen", "leverancier", "price");
fputcsv( $fp, $csvHeader,";");

foreach ($products as $product){
$sku = $product->getSku();
$name = $product->getName();
$afmetingen = $product->getAfmetingen();
$leverancier = $product->getLeverancier();
$price = $product->getPrice();
fputcsv($fp, array($sku, $name, $afmetingen, $leverancier, $price), ";");
}
fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Some attributes are not included in flat tables.
You can try to disable flat products on the fly with:

```
$flatProducts = Mage::helper('catalog/product_flat')->getProcess();
$flatStatus = $process->getStatus();
$flatProducts->setStatus(Mage_Index_Model_Process::STATUS_RUNNING);
```

and re-enable flat status afterwards:

```
$flatProducts->setStatus($flatStatus);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But i am getting an error by trying this.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Notice: Undefined variable: process in /var/www/vhosts/wwwwwww/httpdocs/export.php on line 11' in /var/www/vhosts/wwwwwwwwwwwww/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php:245 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/vhosts/wwwwwwwwww/httpdocs/export.php(11): mageCoreErrorHandler(8, 'Undefined varia...', '/var/www/vhosts...', 11, Array) #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/vhosts/wwwwwwwwwwwww/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 245

Comment: $flatProducts = Mage::helper('catalog/product_flat')->getProcess();
$flatStatus = $process->getStatus();
$flatProducts->setStatus(Mage_Index_Model_Process::STATUS_RUNNING);
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$products->addAttributeToSelect('name');
$products->addAttributeToSelect('afmetingen');
$products->addAttributeToSelect('leverancier');
$products->addAttributeToSelect('price');
$fp = fopen('exports.csv', 'w');

Comment: Still getting the same error. Do I need to replace $products by $flatProducts as well?